# How to terminate a thread in a view scoped bean?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf-2

In our application when a user clicks on commandlink, a pop up is generated. This click will pass an id to process.

My managed bean is viewscoped and I am creating a thread to do some tasks.

In a scenario where a user clicks on the link a pop up is generated and the thread has started executing jobs, say the user closes the pop up and tries to click the link providing a different id this time. My problem is the previous thread which was started is not being destroyed. I can still get the latest id details as a response but the previous thread still executes jobs.

I would like to know if there is a way to terminate the previous instance thread on a new request. I know I can achieve this using sessionscoped but popups are being opened in the same session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as a quick solution possible for your use case:

- I'd use threadpool rather than creating new thread per request (as thread pooling idea is more efficient + provided in standard API)
- then you can easily stop any running thread in pool, solution I've found on: http://www.coderanch.com/t/234197/threads/java/stopping-runnable-ThreadPoolExecutor
  => question contains sample for threadpool implementation and the 1.st answer gives you the solution

calling:

```
boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
```

In your case the call should use:

```
mayInterruptIfRunning=true
```

The only quesion left is: Where to keep the Future reference? :)
We can discuss that if you want as well :)

Comment: b .. thanks a lot for your response. i really appreciate it. i think it did the trick. i used a static boolean variable. on the first time the thread pool runs i set it to true, so on the second request i cancel the current threadpool and create a new instance. i dunno if this the standard way of doing it. i have edited the code in the question. what you say ?

Comment: you would get into trouble, as this would work for one client only (as you use static field - ifinterrupt). In case you have 2 client's one could terminate another one thread. I guess that is not desired behavior :) Rather you need to provide mapping: <session identifier> to future

Comment: oh yes, i totally forgot that...just to clarify, would keeping future in the session work ? ..

Comment: yes, sound's like a way to go :) But it depend's what exactly keeping in the session means for you :) If you'd try to serialize it => that should not work. However I would go for some session scoped bean if possible and keep it there. Or just some static map having session identifier as key and Future as value (but then you need to find out what is the session identifier :)

Comment: B i followed your apporach. now i have a static map with userid as key and future ref as value. thanks a lot for your help .. cheers :)